# My AngularJs code not running working properly getting this error - TypeError: Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]  _> the output i require is this .... when i'm trying to run the code it not working properly, when i use the for loop for printing the result in html its working fine when i tried to change my code concept to angularjs i cannot call the value it says obj,#Object not defined and getting multiple errors

> I'm sharing my code

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="inputs">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div id="result" style="width:600px; text-transform: capitalize;" align="right">Heloo</div>

<div ng-repeat="component in components">


{{mylogic(component)}}

</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("inputs",[]);

app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){

$scope.components=[{
  'name':{
    'fname':'{"placeholder":"First Name","description":"Enter First Name of the user","value":"abc","type":"text"}',
    'lname':'{"placeholder":"Second Name","description":"Enter Last Name of the user","value":"ddd","type":"text"}'
  },
  'password':'{"placeholder":"Password","description":"Enter password","value":"","type":"password"}',
  'dim':{
    'dim2':{
      'dim3':'{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"ssds"}'
    }
  },
  'ary':{
    'ar10':{
      'ary2':{
        'ary3':'{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"acb"}'
      }
    },
    'ary11':''
  }
}];

 var result='';  


 $scope.mylogic=function(obj,source){ 
 /*  console.log(source);*/
  /*console.log(obj,source);
  console.log(typeof source[obj] );*/
   if(typeof source[obj]=='string'){ 
     var val=[];
      if(source[obj]!=""){
    val =JSON.parse(source[obj]);  
      return  obj +' <input type="'+val.type+'" value="'+val.value+'" placeholder="'+val.placeholder+'" type="text" ><br><code>Notes* '+val.description+'</code> <hr>';
     }else{
      return  obj +' <input placeholder="'+obj+'" type="text" > <hr>';
     }
   }else{  // console.log( components[obj] );
     var subObj=source[obj]; var tempObj=[];
      for(item in subObj ){
       // console.log(item,'--',subObj);
       tempObj.push(obj+' > ' +mylogic(item,subObj)  );
      }
     return tempObj;

     /* console.log(tempObj);*/
   }
}

/*for(component in $scope.components){
  result+= mylogic(component,$scope.components);
   console.log('Component',$scope.components[component]);
   console.log(result+= mylogic(component,$scope.components));
   console.log(mylogic);
}
*/
// console.log('Component',$scope.components[component]);
var res=document.getElementById('result');
res.innerHTML=result;
});
```

Comment: please clean the code (remove commented lines) and post the stack trace.

Comment: @JK_Jha : when i'm printing just components its printing the json array ..but when i print {{"mylogic(components)"}} using ng-repeat its not working ..help me if u can

Comment: @AustinKootz :- i posted the output when i'm getting when i do the same program in pure javascript .i'm getting stuck here

Comment: you are missing one parameter `source` for calling function `mylogic `.

Comment: @Pengyy :- i couldn't fix that can you correct me how to do that..i tried that {{mylogic(component,source)}}.still getting error  [ie; TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Array]' of undefined ----- at ChildScope.$scope.mylogic (script.js:33)]

Comment: `$scope.mylogic=function(obj,source){ `  2 arguments but `{{mylogic(component)}}` >> here  you are sending 1 parameter.  and I dont know whether we can call function in `{{`

Comment: @pro.mean :- do you have any solution to solve this .?? its running perfectly in javascript ..but when i do the dame in angular..its making trouble

Comment: @Pengyy :- do you have any idea??? ..even i tried to print the values in console that also not working ..

Comment: You can not call a function in interpolating ...  `{{ ... }}`. use directive for that

Comment: @pro.mean :- it is possible..you can have a try on that ...any other idea you have?

Comment: okay. good to know. can you share `console.log` result through pastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HJw0bq9X :- error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141620/discussion-between-pro-mean-and-deepak-vijay).

Comment: Any one have any idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("inputs", []);
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml;
});
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.components = [{
        'name': {
            'fname': '{"placeholder":"First Name","description":"Enter First Name of the user","value":"abc","type":"text"}',
            'lname': '{"placeholder":"Second Name","description":"Enter Last Name of the user","value":"ddd","type":"text"}'
        },
        'password': '{"placeholder":"Password","description":"Enter password","value":"","type":"password"}',
        'dim': {
            'dim2': {
                'dim3': '{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"ssds"}'
            }
        },
        'ary': {
            'ar10': {
                'ary2': {
                    'ary3': '{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"acb"}'
                }
            },
            'ary11': ''
        }
    }];

    var result = '';


    $scope.mylogic = function(obj, source) {
        if (typeof source[obj] == 'string') {
            var val = [];
            if (source[obj] != "") {
                val = JSON.parse(source[obj]);
                var res = obj + ' <input type="' + val.type + '" value="' + val.value + '" placeholder="' + val.placeholder + '" type="text" ><br><code>Notes* ' + val.description + '</code> <hr>';
                return res;
            } else {
                var res = obj + ' <input placeholder="' + obj + '" type="text" > <hr>';
                return res;
            }

        } else { // console.log( components[obj] );
            var subObj = source[obj];
            var res = '';
            for (item in subObj) {
                // console.log(item,'--',subObj);
                res += obj + ' > ' + $scope.mylogic(item, subObj);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="inputs">

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div id="result" style="width:600px; text-transform: capitalize;" align="right">Heloo</div>

    <div ng-repeat="component in components">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in component" ng-bind-html="mylogic(key,component) | unsafe">

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Check it

Comment: :- i need a method to print without using 2 ng-repeats...i want to print it with a single ng-repeat and if it should be done by calling the{{ mylogic()}}  ex:- ng-repeat (components in components) and calling {{mylogic(component)}}

Comment: :- can yo help me to do in that way i mentioned above?

Comment: @DeepakVijay if you want one ng-repeat , then remove [] from $scope.components and do this `<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in components" ng-bind-html="mylogic(key,components) | unsafe">`

Comment: -Thank you so much for help ..you solved my headache..i was running behind this for last 3 days :) ..

Comment: can you please help with other thing i will share my code pen with you .i ust want to convert it into angular JS